# BackgroundTaskHost and SearchProtocolHost are downloading heavyly in the background

Tags: windows, networking, windows-10, download

I am using Windows 10, recently I noticed my windows box has downloaded hundreds of gigabytes in a week, I installed NetBalancer to get network traffic statistics.

I noticed BackgroundTaskHost.exe, BackgroundTransferHost.exe and SearchProtocolHost.exe have generated half of the traffic, any idea why this is happening ? any tool to use to see my network usage over time based on applications/processes ?